# Is there a way to implement checkout to an existing web functionality from React Native App

Tags: react-native, shopify

so I have react native e-commerce application. On top of that I am using shopify and I have an already working web version where customers do everything from checking products to paying for them. My problem is, on my react native app, I want customers to view products on app, add to cart( a functionality that I already have implemented) but on the checkout part, I want users to checkout their products on the web version so to ease payment and stuff.

The WebView should open and should have the products the user wanted to checkout. Please give ideas, perceptions and maybe solutions

Comment: check https://github.com/sellflow/sellflow

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use [InAppBrowser](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser) instead of WebView for payment processes, it's more secure and very simple to implement.

You need to open payment link like [Stripe Payment Links](https://stripe.com/payments/payment-links), inside in-app-browser. Use [openAuth](https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser#authentication-flow-using-deep-linking) method with deeplinks integration to automatically close browser after payment is finish.